# Github commit shows wrong account as author

Tags: github

I ended up making two github account (don't remember why) but now I only use one of them. Every time I use the GUI from here (http://windows.github.com/) to commit and sync my changes for a project on the newer account I use, the author is listed as the older account that I no longer use. What do I need to change on my computer to associate any future commits with the newer account. I read something about this being related to email addresses so I changed that to match and I also remove ssh keys from the older account. How do I let it know that I want to commit using the newer account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your `.gitconfig` file.
Maybe the file exist in your user home directory like `C:/Users/USERNAME/`

Comment: I think this is the problem- I've changed the account using the 'git config' command. The token hasn't changed though. I've tried looking up how to find the token for a certain account and I only see references to the API token which is no longer used, and I can't find any token on my account page. Do you know where I can get the appropriate token to use?

Comment: commit author is not related to token. it's related with `git config`. there are two configs, global and local. so you have to check which account(name and email) is specified in `$USER/.gitconfig` and `REPOSITORY/.git/config`

Comment: This worked perfectly. I changed the email in the .gitconfig file and now my pushes are appearing under my new account.

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer from Outsider, if you are on Mac and you have this issue, simply go into your `/Users/USERNAME` folder and `cat .gitconfig`, if the `name` and `email` fields are incorrect, just `vim .gitconfig` and change them.